# Using pivot on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the following sample data in an Oracle table (tab1) and I am trying to convert rows to columns. With pivot table I am able to have person_id like intended but in columns I can only achieve to have every job_id in different column and salary in rows. Is it possible to get it in form I need?

Sample data:

| person_id | job_id | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 100 |
| 1 | 51 | 125 |
| 2 | 51 | 115 |
| 2 | 54 | 105 |
| 2 | 55 | 80 |

My intended output:

| person_id | job_1 | salary_1 | job_2 | salary_2 | job_3 | salary_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 100 | 51 | 125 | null | null |
| 2 | 51 | 115 | 54 | 105 | 55 | 80 |

I tried to use pivot somehow as here I found similar problems:
https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2018/05/28/generic-pivot-function/

[Using pivot on multiple columns of an Oracle row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939244/using-pivot-on-multiple-columns-of-an-oracle-row)

As It is not exaclty the same I'm stuck trying by trial and error as well as searching google for simillar question but I cannot find any.

[SQL Pivot on multiple columns with INT and NVARCHAR datatypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65909526/sql-pivot-on-multiple-columns-with-int-and-nvarchar-datatypes)   - best answer here could help me but I can't have every job_id in different column as there is around 1000 different jobs and every person has 2-5 jobs. It means that I can have 5*2+1 columns at max.

I am using oracle 19 if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to number the jobs for each person and then `PIVOT` based on those numbers:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY job_id) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(job_id) AS job_id,
  MAX(salary) AS salary
  FOR rn IN (1 AS J1, 2 AS J2, 3 AS J3)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (person_id, job_id, salary) AS
SELECT 1, 50, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 51, 125 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 51, 115 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 54, 105 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 55,  80 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| PERSON_ID | J1_JOB_ID | J1_SALARY | J2_JOB_ID | J2_SALARY | J3_JOB_ID | J3_SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 100 | 51 | 125 | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | 51 | 115 | 54 | 105 | 55 | 80 |

*Note: If you want to rename the columns then use aliases such as `SELECT person_id, j1_job_id AS job_1, ...`.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z7v7TY9k)

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thank you very much, that's exaclty what I need. However would it be possible to have dynamic number of columns? For example if I write clause 'WHERE t.person_id = 1' after FROM table_name t I would get in return just nulls in J3 columns. Can i get rid of them somehow?

https://dbfiddle.uk/3cIN4ueH

Comment: @ORA20001 SQL (not just Oracle's dialect) requires a fixed number of columns in a query. You could use dynamic SQL to work out the maximum columns you need for a query and then only generate that query but it's easier just to generate all 5 pairs of columns and then ignore the extra ones if you don't need it in whatever third-party program you are using to access the database (i.e. Java, Python, C#, PHP, etc.).